# Getting memsize of shared Array space

Tags: ruby, memory-management

### tl;dr

```
require 'objspace'

ObjectSpace.memsize_of([0] * 1_000_000)
#=> 8000040
ObjectSpace.memsize_of(Array.new([0] * 1_000_000))
#=> 40
```

Where did it go?

### Longer version

A whole bunch of stuff inside Array seems to have a concept of a "shared array" where the data block gets moved to a shared heap space. I'm aware that `memsize_of` makes it clear that it may be incomplete, but is there a (good?) way to analyze the allocation of these shared array blocks? They don't seem to be "objects" from the point of view of `ObjectSpace.each_object`. For the purposes of this memory profiler it would be nice to at least be able to track the overall size of the shared array heap space even if I can't trace it back to specific objects.

Comment: `ObjectSpace.memsize_of(([0] * 1_000_000).dup)` (or `clone`) returns `40`, too.

Comment: A thing which might be part of an answer: `ObjectSpace.dump` will tell you that the array is shared and give you a pointer that I think is the underlying shared allocation, but you can't turn that back into something to hand to `memsize_of`. Could be enough (combined with knowing the size) to estimate the shared array memory usage.

Comment: Further complication on the above, if you are trying to measure the memory usage of some specific chunk of code, you can have an array object pointing at a shared buffer that was created before your block, so I need to check for the earliest generation with the same `reference` pointer I think.

Comment: BTW, why do you want to track these shared arrays?

Comment: I'm working on a memory profiler tool for Chef and because of how Chef's internal data structures work, most arrays get wrapped in the equivalent of `Array.new`, thus possibly triggering the shared heap relocation behavior. I could just ignore it since this is a best-estimate approach anyway, but would be nice to track.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately `rb_ary_memsize` is a public function, so with small hack, you can do it:

```
#include <ruby.h>
#include <assert.h>

/* private macros from array.c */
#define ARY_OWNS_HEAP_P(a) (!FL_TEST((a), ELTS_SHARED|RARRAY_EMBED_FLAG))
#define ARY_SHARED_P(ary) \
    (assert(!FL_TEST((ary), ELTS_SHARED) || !FL_TEST((ary), RARRAY_EMBED_FLAG)), \
     FL_TEST((ary),ELTS_SHARED)!=0)

RUBY_FUNC_EXPORTED size_t
rb_ary_memsize(VALUE ary)
{
    if (ARY_OWNS_HEAP_P(ary)) {
        return RARRAY(ary)->as.heap.aux.capa * sizeof(VALUE);
    }
/* -------8<------8<------- */
    else if (ARY_SHARED_P(ary)){
        /* if it is a shared array, calculate size using length of shared root */
        return RARRAY_LEN(RARRAY(ary)->as.heap.aux.shared) * sizeof(VALUE);
    }
/* ------->8------>8------- */
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Compile it into shared object:

```
gcc $(ruby -rrbconfig \
  -e'puts RbConfig::CONFIG.values_at("rubyhdrdir","rubyarchhdrdir").map{|d| " -I#{d}"}.join') \
  -Wall -fpic -shared -o ary_memsize_hack.so ary_memsize_hack.c
```

And load into process replacing original function:

```
LD_PRELOAD="$(pwd)/ary_memsize_hack.so" ruby -robjspace \
  -e 'p ObjectSpace.memsize_of([0] * 1_000_000); 
      p ObjectSpace.memsize_of(Array.new([0] * 1_000_000))'
```

It will produce desired output:

```
8000040
8000040
```

**UPDATE**:
`rb_ary_memsize` function which in charge of estimating array size, only does it for arrays, which are owning the heap (i.e. not shared and not embedded), and returns zero otherwise. In general it makes sense, because if you supposed to calculate size of all arrays in the applications, eventually the numbers should match, while with my patch the contents of shared arrays will be counted multiple times. I guess main problem is the way how the wrapping array constructed on the ruby side: essentially the reference on inner array lost, and is not reachable by the application code, and looks like uncountable. My patch only demonstrates how to reach the root of the shared array to expose the size, but I don't think this should be integrated into upstream in any way. The similar problem would be with embedded arrays, for the ruby also returns 0 as the size, which does not show what the application expect to see:

```
require 'objspace'

puts ObjectSpace.dump([1])
#=> {"address":"0x000008033f9bd8", "type":"ARRAY", "class":"0x000008029f9a98", "length":1, 
#    "embedded":true, "memsize":40, "flags":{"wb_protected":true}}
puts ObjectSpace.dump([1, 2])
#=> {"address":"0x000008033f9b38", "type":"ARRAY", "class":"0x000008029f9a98", "length":2, 
#    "embedded":true, "memsize":40, "flags":{"wb_protected":true}}
puts ObjectSpace.dump([1, 2, 3])
#=> {"address":"0x000008033f9ac0", "type":"ARRAY", "class":"0x000008029f9a98", "length":3, 
#    "embedded":true, "memsize":40, "flags":{"wb_protected":true}}
puts ObjectSpace.dump([1, 2, 3, 4])
#=> {"address":"0x000008033f9a48", "type":"ARRAY", "class":"0x000008029f9a98", "length":4,
#    "memsize":72, "flags":{"wb_protected":true}}
```

Comment: Could you add more of an explanation of why it happens in the first place? Also is there a less hacky way then recompiling our own version? Maybe something with `Fiddle`?

Comment: I've updated the answer with clarifications, unfortunately I didn't use `Fiddle` API previously, probably it would be easier, but with `LD_PRELOAD` it would be more robust. Also I think that ruby behaviror in regard to shared arrays is correct. The application should really create shared array with intention to share array contents, not to wrap it.